# When a new node gene is added, is it given a global or local new number? Neat

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

I am trying to implement a NEAT (NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies) algorithm in python, but after watching multiple guides and reading the original paper, I am left with one question. When a new node/neuron is created, is it then given a global number or a local number for its node genes?

The paper makes it sound like global number, but if that is the case there might be a mistake where the connection genes are different even though the connection is the same, if the order the node was created is different; However, if its local, the coming from and going to connection gene/the in out connection gene would be different depending on the NN. Hopefully it makes sense, if not let me know any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not even sure "local number" even makes sense! The idea of the innovation numbers is precisely so that we can easily compare structures between different genomes.

When new nodes are created, normally one connection is split in two, adding a new node in the middle. This event is stored in a log, so if later on a different genome tries to create a new node by splitting the same connection, then the same innovation numbers are used.

Of course, in a bit of a roundabout way it is possible to create two genomes with the same structure but different innovation numbers. This is simply accepted.

I am adding a diagram with one such example, let me know if you were thinking about a different situation:

[image]

Note that some implementations have innovation numbers for both connections and nodes, while others only have such numbers for nodes, connections being fully described by the nodes they connect. In the first case it is also possible to end up having equivalent connections with different innovation numbers, but that is fine as well. There has been a bit of debate around this finer details, but in practice it seems the effects are minimal if anything.